# Spring 4 change jsp when async task has finished

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am developing a spring 4 mvc application and I've got a database transaction that has to be done in the background.

It is triggered, when the URL `/paramters_selected` is called. The controller then starts an asynchronous task that is going to take a few minutes. For the time of processing the task, I return "processing" so that the controller method will render the `/processing` - JSP view. When the background task is finished, the "result" view should be rendered.

Is it possible, and if so how would it be done, to call `/result` when the background transaction has finished? Furthermore, is it possible to constantly update the "processing" view so that some kind of progress bar could be used?

Additonally, what kind of "technique" is best suited for this problem? I came across the terms of async-methods in spring, completable futures, deferredresult and listenablefuture.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Async then i would suggest you not to wait for the result from server and better keep on either refreshing the status after some time or create callback which keeps on listening to response from server for Async Tasks.

If you use progress bar till Async task is completed, i suppose you mean just to show in UI and HTTP connection for that request is completed once the request is sent to Async task otherwise holding resource is not good as it will impact performance of the system and other tasks waiting for resource will eventually die due to unavailability of free resources.

So for Async task you can use any of the Java messaging queue, wherein your task will be pushing into JMS queue and Async task will keep of deque from JMS queue and once task is completed send response in form of notificaiton to originating task.

Answer (score 1):

By using WebSocket you can implement this feature in a real time way.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html